# How to get correct position in the std::string?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a custom single line edit control, with a custom font in win32 api on windows 7, the font is not a fixed width font, and I need to move caret according to the mouse click, The edit control is not empty and if I know the horizontal position of the mouse click within the window, how do I calculate the number of characters after which I need to move caret to ?

I really am out of ideas, if it was a fixed width font, I would have divided the horizontal mouse click position with average character width, that would have been simpler, doing the same with not a fixed width font, is prone to errors.

Comment: Try some ideas on your own. If it doesn't work, post your code and explain the problem you are facing. Without that, it is hard for others to help.

Comment: @RSahu I really am out of ideas, if it was a fixed width font, I would have divided the horizontal mouse click position with character width, that would have been simpler, doing the same with not a fixed width font, taking average character width, is prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's a single-line control, you probably don't plan on working with immensely long input (at least normally). That being the case, one possibility would be to just store the character positions in an array (or vector, etc.) Then you can use (for example) a binary search in that array to find character positions. Of course, you *can* do the same even for longer strings--though it can increase storage requirements quite a bit.

Comment: I'll add that probably to fill such a vector `GetTextExtentPoint32` will come handy.

Comment: @Matteo: in this case GetCharWidth32 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144862(v=vs.85).aspx) might be more useful as it retrieves the positions for each character. I suppose this can also be done at runtime for the mouse-click itself reducing the memory consumption.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Good idea, but isn't it going to be a bit slow ? I mean we need to update the caret position in real time. Also what if somebody copy-pasted a long string, it will take a lot of time to calculate each character's position.

Answer (score 1):

This is a familiar problem. You are in essence trying to do hit testing on text and for that you need the location on the screen of each character of the text.

My preferred strategy is to calculate an array of RECT, one for each character of displayed text. The array needs to be updated when text is added or deleted, but it easily handles single or multiple lines. The function GetCharWidth32 retrieves all the widths for a string of text in a particular font selected into a DC. For single line one call is enough, and calculating the array of RECTs is simple. It's not much harder to do multiline.

Handle the mouse down message, loop through the array and find the right character. A brute force search is plenty fast enough.

This method is simple and easily generalises to a range of similar problems.